# Filling char[] with row matrix and loop over all rows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, platformio

I want to print my `Mag` array. With the current API I can only print by row using `ESP_LOGI`. So I have to fill a row string (char[]) and display in loop:

```
//char s[2 * (w - 2 * window - 1)];
char[200];
char s_tmp[4]; //one element of array string
for(int i=window; i<=w-window;++i){
    memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
    memset(s_tmp, 0, sizeof(s_tmp)); // Fill with \0 for ESP_LOGI
    for(int j=window; j<h-window;++j){
        sprintf(s_tmp, "%u", Mag[i + j * w]);
        strcat(s, s_tmp);
        strcat(s, ".");
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"%s", s);
}
```

}

**Output**:
Serial output read with ***VScode platformIO***

Size = (h=28, w=28)
window = 3

```
I (13793) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.2.1.1.1.0.0.1.0.2.1.0.0.0.1.0.2.0.0.1.          m
I (13793) camera_httpd: 0.0.1.0.4.1.1.1.0.1.2.0.2.1.0.0.0.1.0.1.2.0.
I (13793) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.1.1.0.1.1.0.0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.2.1.1.0.0.        [0m
I (13803) camera_htt       pd: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.2.2.1.1.
I (13813) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.1.0.0.0.1.1.1.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.1.1.
I (13823) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.       1.0.0.0.0.1.0.2.2.
I (13823) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.2.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.1.0.2.
I (13833) camera_httpd: 1.0.0.0.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.       0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.
I (13843) camera_httpd: 0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.
```

I would like to know why it displays space. I am guessing those come from my memset(0).
Is their any better way to do it?

Comment: I think I like the spaces.  It makes a good visual distinction between `null` areas and data filled areas.  Why exactly do you not?  (`memset` just did what you asked it to do, fill sizeof(type)*(number of array elements) memory locations owith `\0` (or `0`) )

Comment: @ryyker: basically their shouldn't be that much null areas. I might made a mistake on s size : `2 * (w - 2*window- 1)`. It should be `[window, h-window-1]`. But even with this changes there is the same 8 `null` spaces.

Comment: The array indexing here is pretty complicated, and difficult to track.  There certainly could be errors.

Comment: `s_tmp[2];` only well defined for printing values [0-9].  Attempting other values?

Comment: `char s[42]` too small for 25 digit/space. need at least 51. Try `char s[200];` and see if things improve.

Comment: if after all of this conversation, in your mind the question _Is their any better way to do it?_ still exists, would you mind defining _better_?  i.e. Maybe instead of blank spaces, you would prefer `*`, or some other symbol?  ( `memset(s, '*', sizeof(s));` )

Comment: @ryyker: the advange of 0 it had \0 at the end of my string in ESP_LOGI

Comment: Okay, clarify _better_ please :)  I am unclear about what you are asking.

Comment: How do you know they are spaces and not a a tab or other white space?  `strcat(s, " ");` --> `strcat(s, ".");` may help ID the source of trouble.

Comment: `memset(s_tmp, 0, sizeof(s_tmp)); // Fill with \0 for ESP_LOGI` makes little sense.  `memset` should not be needed for this code nor `ESP_LOSI()`.  Try `ESP_LOGI(TAG,"%s", s);` --> `printf("<%s>\n", s);` to help separate the issues.

Comment: Making `s_tmp` 2 characters long, with no checks in your code to see if you're writing past it, is bad coding practice.

Comment: Suggest `sprintf(s_tmp, "%u", Mag[i + j * w]);` --> `sprintf(s_tmp, "%u", Mag[i + j * w]%10u);` to set aside one of [@TomKarzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489275/filling-char-with-row-matrix-and-loop-over-all-rows?noredirect=1#comment108773463_61489275) good concerns.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the code you posted.  There are spaces everywhere including inside the words `(10873) camera_h       ttpd`

Comment: My conclusion: various weakness to this code yet the extra space issue is inside `ESP_LOGI(TAG,"%s", s);`.  As spaces come up here and there in groups of 8, perhaps some failing coversion to tab code?  Good luck.

Comment: Ok this has nothing to do with the code and  I am sorry... It's related to platformIO plugin from VScode which doesn't handle well special shell control characters  for changing the color of the line

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you can answer to close this thread ty.

Comment: @Katsu You can [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to [platformIO extension VScode terminal](https://community.platformio.org/t/some-bizare-characters-prints-on-serial-monitor-with-esp-idf-hello-world-example/5025) which doesn't handle well special shell control characters for changing the color of the line.

Serial output read from ***PuTTY***:

```
I (42273) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
I (42273) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.
I (42283) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.1.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.
I (42293) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.4.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.
I (42293) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.1.0.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.
I (42303) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.1.
I (42313) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.3.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.1.0.1.0.
I (42323) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.1.0.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.
I (42323) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.0.1.0.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.0.1.0.0.0.1.0.1.
I (42333) camera_httpd: 0.5.1.1.3.1.0.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
I (42343) camera_httpd: 0.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.1.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
```